# how-to-reset-remove-bios-password-on-the-hp-stream 14 0ax

Tags: bios, password-recovery, cmos

There was a user named Moab that stated he could generate an admin pw from the code it spits out after 3 failed attempts, can anyone still do this for me? I am desperate (helping a friend). My code is: i 70256311
Please help!

Comment: [Dogbert's Blog: BIOS Password Backdoors in Laptops](https://dogber1.blogspot.co.uk/2009/05/table-of-reverse-engineered-bios.html)

Comment: According to [CherylG on this HP Support Forum post](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Operating-System-and-Recovery/forgotten-bios-admin-password-hp-stream-14-ax010wm/td-p/6163203), "there is no passcode for halt codes beginning with an i. [The only two options are] either remove the RTC battery on [the] motherboard and hold the power button in for 30 seconds [or] contact HP." However, some other posts suggested trying https://bios-pw.org and entering the code without the `i` prefix.